# SpecFlow to mimic MVC / EF behaviour with Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, specflow

We're handling the EF context problem by having the same instance on a Per-Web-Request basis in Unity.

That works perfectly, but we've now introduced SpecFlow to write BDD specifications.

Most of our SpecFlow steps go to the controller directly, so we we would like to mimic the same environment that a controller will find when running on the IIS world.

How can this be done?

The closest we got was to create a child Unity container on SpecFlow's BeforeStep, but that doesn't necessarily mean that each controller call will have a different context instance (like when you actually make an HTTP request thru IIS).
We really need to mimic the HTTP call environment on the controller otherwise the specifications may not catch issues in production code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpSImulator, might help. (http://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpSimulator/)